# A word to describe the next level of action

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe the next level of action? I know there is but I can't remember the word.

For example, if plan A fails, plan B is the next level of action to take. And if plan B fails, the next level of action to take is plan C.

So in this case, plan B is a *what* of plan A, and plan C is a *what* of plan B. The *what* is the word I'm trying to find.

Comment: It is now more common, popular (and widely understood) to use the term *Plan B* itself. Keep it simple, all plans after A are *Plan B* in the sense of a fallback option. Since OP already has the answer in it, I am posting this as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase "contingency plan" comes to mind first, for me.  "Fallback" is another term you might find useful.

Comment: I've upvoted, but really I think you have your two offerings the wrong way round. If Plan A unexpectly fails and Plan B is implemented, Plan B is the **fallback**, even if it had never been thought of *until* Plan A failed. But **contingency plan** carries the strong implication that it was worked out long before (perhaps in parallel with Plan A), with at least some degree of expectation that Plan A *might* fail, or even *was likely* to fail.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe xEnOn's post implies exactly what you describe - Plan B was previously determined to be the fallback for Plan A.  So, "contingency plan" does apply.  Perhaps the reason this term comes to mind first for me is because I work in [security.se].

Comment: I really couldn't say from OP's phrasing whether he specifically wants to identify the relationship between the preferred and the pre-planned alternative course of action, or a previously-unplanned one hastily conjured up when Plan A was seen to be a failure. My point is simply that *fallback* comfortably covers both, but *contingency* sits uneasy in the second scenario.